# Oracle query generation

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g

I have a text box that is filled with date(date type) from a date picker.

I have a table with 3 columns(name,fromdate(date),todate(date)). On button click activity it should show only those names which have the date specified between the from date and to date.

I would like some help me on this

```
   string v = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["harish"].ConnectionString;
    con = new OracleConnection(v);
    con.Open(); 
    cmd = new OracleCommand("________", con);
```

Comment: Have you tried to write any SQL statements at all?

Comment: @EvanM :yes i did.im new to query writing and ive written all sorts of combos but not able to get this one  for the past hr! :(

Answer (score 2):

You're not even trying.  Try Oracle and MSDN for this.

But since you're in a jam....

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;      
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;         
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table (name, fromDate, toDate)VALUES(:nameVal, :fromVal, :toVal)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":fromVal", OracleType.DateTime)).Value = fromDateVal;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":toVal", OracleType.DateTime)).Value = toDateVal;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//close the connection after done.... release the resources
```

Comment: i've been trying this for the past hour and still stuck with this!i desperatly need help for this!

Comment: i want to insert the columns only if the date i chose in the date picker is between the fromdate and todate specified in the table.i have to display this in a GridView from the database to the GridView

Comment: One thing you could do is select from the table to see if it is within the range.  If it is then insert it to your table.